# curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Tags: curl, saucelabs

I'm trying to upload a ipa file to saucelabs storage but getting the error as mentioned above.

The command that I'm using -

```
$ curl -F 'payload=@/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/<file_name>.ipa' -F name=<file_name>.apk -u "$SAUCE_USERNAME:$SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY"  'https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/v1/storage/upload'
```

I'm on mac. I've seen the questions on stackoverflow but none of them answers.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to resolve this by not using single or double quotes around the file name.

```
curl -u "<userName>:<accessKey>" \
-X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/xcuitest/v2/test-suite" \
-F file=@/path/to/app/file/Application-debug-test.zip
```

Comment: this worked for me. though a colleague of mine was able to run our command (which  was very similar to the example here) with quotes, so I wonder if the coniguration of each individual machine matters here?

Answer (score 7):

There might be a problem escaping your path. For me your command works, if the file is correct (I get an unauthorized of course). (curl 7.64.1)

Try your command from the Downloads folder:

```
cd /Users/<user-name>/Downloads
curl -F @<file_name>.ipa -F name=<file_name>.apk -u "$SAUCE_USERNAME:$SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY"  'https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/v1/storage/upload'
```

You may have to escape characters in your filename. **Tip**: You can also try drag and drop the file form finder to Terminal while the cursor is at the point where the filename is. Terminal will escape those automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by replacing ***single quotes*** with ***double quotes*** instead.

I changed this:

```
curl -F 'file=@addresses.json' https://location-bq-datasets.cloudfunctions.net/sample-endpoint
```

`curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application`

To this:

```
curl -F "file=@addresses.json" https://location-bq-datasets.cloudfunctions.net/sample-endpoint
```

You also don't need to place your endpoint `https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/v1/storage/upload` in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to making sure the quotes were in the correct place, I had to remove the tilde that I first included in my file path.

**Bad:**

```
curl -F dsym=@"~/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/<file_name>.dSYM.zip" -H "X-APP-LICENSE-KEY: theKey" https://theplaceto.upload
```

**Good:**

````
curl -F dsym=@"/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/<file_name>.dSYM.zip" -H "X-APP-LICENSE-KEY: theKey" https://theplaceto.upload```**
````

Answer (score 1):

For me I was using iTerm on MacOS and noticed this issue. I found out it was because iTerm did not have access to my Downloads folder and even though I was trying to access that folder there was no prompt. After I went into settings and enabled access to the Downloads folder this issue was fixed for me.

[image: Mac settings windows showing file options]

Answer (score 0):

Use below command for me it resolved

```
curl -F "file=@C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/git/ppt/8.apk" http://localhost:8000/api/v1/upload -H "Authorization:f06ecb3505899296f03b0c21d7dc5baf83fb999e3d0b4c1243874c82c0184874"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you're not in the right folder that contains the file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a content type for it to work: `-H 'Content-Type: "application/zip"'`